# Space out every 4 numbers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have an input box which is limited to 16 Numbers. What I'd like to do for aesthetics would be to place a gap per 4 numbers.

EG. 
When a person enters

> 1234567891234567

It should look like this

> 1234 5678 9123 4567

How would this be possible on Key Up in JQuery?

Comment: I would consider (and recommend) adding 4 separate text boxes and adding code to automatically jump to the next text box when the text box is full.

Comment: Damn, was hoping to just get it done in a single box

Comment: I would recommend not doing it on keyup as it can be annoying. Imagine while you type 12335 and you realize you made a mistake, you instinctively backspace twice to correct the 3, but there is now an extra space.  Better to do it when the field loses focus

Comment: `@`Donald: You can do it, I just think it will be a) easier for you to implement, and b) a better UI for users.

Comment: it is annoyingly complicated when you try to edit something in the middle..

Comment: @Rodolfo: Not really a problem, you'd check whether the char-to-delete is a space, and delete all the spaces automatically.

Comment: @Matt yes but then the reverse applies, you see a space so you backspace twice and suddenly the space is not there anymore so you delete an extra char.  Also, doing it at blur helps you if someone copy/pastes the whole entry in the field  (another reason why I'm not a fan of multiple fields, makes copy/pasting a pain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of the [modulus function](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/Modulus.htm):

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ((($this.val().length+1) % 5)==0){
            $this.val($this.val() + " ");
        }
    });
```

[**-- SEE DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y5FN/)

However its a bit buggy, but could be a good starting point for you.

As other users have mentioned, this would not be good for usability, and it would be best to use 4 text boxes (if the length is always 16) and use something like this:

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val().length>=4){
         $this.next().focus();   
        }
    });
```

[**-- SEE DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y5FN/1/)

Again, might be a bit buggy, I'm just pointing out different methods.

Comment: It is annoyingly when you try to edit something.. as it would automatically move carot to end of the text. :P

Comment: @Matt Good point Matt. I've mentioned the scripts a bit buggy. I'm really just demonstrating the use of the modulus function.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution:

```
$(function() {

    $('#my-input')
    .blur(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        value = value.match(/.{1,4}/g).join(" ");
        $(this).val(value);
    })
    .focus(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        value = value.replace(/\s/g, '');
        $(this).val(value);
    });

});
```

You can have a look at that working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xCCWC/1/).

I added a `focus` event to make it more user-friendly. To sum up:

- on blur (i.e. when leaving the input): split every 4 chars;
- on focus (i.e. when editing the input): remove the previously added whitespaces.

Comment: +1 Very nice. Might defeat the point of the feature though as I would imagine the characters are split up for ease of reading when inputting, but still a very good solution.

Comment: Could just use `value.match(/.{1,4}/g).join(" ")`

Answer (score 1):

Try below solution if you consider having it in multiple textbox.

```
$(function() {
    var charLimit = 4;
    $(".inputs").keydown(function(e) {

        var keys = [8, 9, /*16, 17, 18,*/ 19, 20, 27, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 45, 46, 144, 145];

        if (e.which == 8 && this.value.length == 0) {
            $(this).prev('.inputs').focus();
        } else if ($.inArray(e.which, keys) >= 0) {
            return true;
        } else if (this.value.length >= charLimit) {
            $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
            return false;
        } else if (e.shiftKey || e.which <= 48 || e.which >= 58) {
            return false;
        }
    }).keyup (function () {
        if (this.value.length >= charLimit) {
            $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

It has following features,

> 1. Autotabs to next input
> 2. Only numeric
> 3. charLimit - to set to different length

**DEMO:**  http://jsfiddle.net/skram/qygB2/20/

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `keypress` handler here:

```
$("#someinput").on('keypress',function(){
  var currval = this.value.replace(/\s+/g,'');
  return (this.value += currval.length && currval.length%4 < 1 ? ' ' : '', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val.length >= 4){
        $(this).next().focus();
    }
});
```

EDIT:
Well your example is not as good as this one above, so I added this instead.

Answer (score 0):

### Done with keyup

```
$('#textbox').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var val = this.value;
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 46) {  // handle delete and backspace
        if (val.replace(/\s/g, '').length % 4 == 0) {
            $(this).val(val + ' ');
        }
    } else {
        $(this).val(val);        
    }
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DvQ5X/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

here is another solution which you might want to consider

```
OnBlur = function()
{
    var value = $('#txtName').val().replace(/\s/g, "");
    var numberOfSpaces = Math.ceil(value.length / 4)-1;
    while(numberOfSpaces >0)
    {
        value = value.substr(0,numberOfSpaces*4) + ' ' + value.substr(numberOfSpaces*4);
        numberOfSpaces--;
    }
}
```